# How can I receive more information about Jasmine / Protractor timeouts?

Tags: debugging, jasmine, visual-studio-code, protractor

I try to debug the Protractor tests that contains many `browser.wait` statements.

I receive following error message:

`Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.configuration-parser.js:50 at ontimeout (timers.js:475:11) configuration-parser.js:50  at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:310:5) configuration-parser.js:50`

(repeated few times)

that doesn't help me at all.

Is it possible to force Protractor / Jasmine to provide information on which. particular condition it waits during debugging of an application? Or at least when it crashes, provide information for which condition it waited before timeout exception was raised.

This could help me to understand what is going on, in which step my tests really crashes. I've tried to debug tests step by step, but it also doesn't help, since it seems that code is not really executed when Visual Studio code stops in particular line, but after going through `expect` statement.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that is possible to know on which script it occurs.
I had the same problem and putting bigger jasmine timeout in conf.js file resolved the issue:

```
defaultTimeoutInterval: 2000000,
```